# Remove deactivated users from Okta groups via Postman

Tags: postman, okta, okta-api

We've done a poor job of removing deactivated users from Okta groups. I would like to clean that up but there is now way to do so via the UI. I tried this in Postman but receive an error that the HTTP method is not supported by the endpoint.

```
{{url}}/api/v1/groups/00g1avm8w61q5ChdB0h8/users/users?filter=status eq "DEPROVISIONED"
```

I also tried:

```
{{url}}/api/v1/groups/00g1avm8w61q5ChdB0h8/users?filter=status eq "DEPROVISIONED"
```

and

```
{{url}}/api/v1/groups/00g1avm8w61q5ChdB0h8/users/filter=status eq "DEPROVISIONED"
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You probably should use `DELETE` method for removing a user from a group. Also, by looking at the API docs it looks like the `/api/v1/groups/:id/users` endpoint does not support filter parameter. Maybe you should first make a `GET` request to `/api/v1/users` with a filter parameter go get the targeted users, and then to a `DELETE` request to the `/api/v1/groups/:id/users` endpoint to remove those users one by one from this group.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the deactivated user, check the groups tab and there should be an X to click to remove the user from groups even though in group management interface it only lists active users.

It can be done via the UI, it's just not obvious.  It's possible this was changed since the question was asked but given the UI's a bit confusing it's still worth putting out there.